# How to print exponents in 4x4x4 = 64 form in Java

Tags: java

I have created a java program which calculate the exponent(power) of a number. The program is working fine but I want to know how to print the result in this form
`nxnxn = n`.

Below is my program

```
long number=3;
long exponent=4;
long result=number;
for (int i=1;i<exponent;i++)
{
    result=result*number;

    System.out.println(number +" x " + number + " = " +result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print strings in one line you need to use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

Also you need to move the output of the result out of the loop and print the multiplication sign only if it is not the last multiplication

```
long number = 4;
long exponent = 3;
long result = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
    result = result * number;

    System.out.print(number);
    if(i < exponent - 1) {
        System.out.print(" x ");
    }
}
System.out.println(" = " + result);
```

Output

```
4 x 4 x 4 = 64
```

Comment: To print the exponent values you can user`Math.pow()` in Java

Answer (score 4):

You can store this `value(NxNxN...)` in a `String`

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(number+"");
for (int i=1; i<exponent; i++) {
    str.append("x").append(number);
    result = result * number;
}
System.out.println(str + " = " + result);
```

Comment: Better use the `StringBuilder` class, since `'x' + number` creates new string each iteration

Answer (score 1):

I would just simply create `n` element list with `exponent` times repeated `number` and then join it to string

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(exponent, number);
String resultString = String.join("x", list) + " = " + result;
System.out.println(resultString);
```

You can also create new array and use `Arrays.fill()` method

Answer (score 0):

Since the number can get kinda long, why don't you save it in a StringBuilder? or even a string then add them each time in the loop in the end print the result outside the loop as follows

```
String equationStr = "";
long number=3;
long exponent=4;
long result=number;
for (int i=1;i<exponent;i++)
{
    result=result*number;
    if(i < exponent - 1)
        equationStr += result + "×";
    else
        equationStr += String.valueOf(number);

    
}

System.out.println(equationStr + " = " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number = 4;
    long exponent = 3;
    System.out.println(number + (" x " + number).repeat((int) exponent - 1)
        + " = " + (int) Math.pow(number, exponent));
}
```

output:

```
4 x 4 x 4 = 64
```